# Object.getOwnPropertyNames() doesn't appear to return all accessible properties

Tags: javascript

When I run this code in a JavaScript console (I've tried Firefox and Chromium):

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  //console.log(this);
};
xhttp.onerror = function(err) {
  console.log("Error: ");
  console.log(err);
  console.log("Error properties: ");
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err));
}
xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.google.com/", true); // CORS-blocking page to trigger the error
xhttp.send();
```

I get this response:

[image]

My question is why `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` doesn't return all the properties I can see from `console.log()`? What happened to `target`, `bubbles`, etc.?

It is my understanding that `getOwnPropertyNames()` should return all properties, so why are there a bunch missing? Are these a special type of property?

If I wanted (I do) a fool-proof way to list all properties on an object, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why Object.getOwnPropertyNames() doesn't return all the properties I can see from console.log()?

The "own" in `getOwnPropertyNames` means it only gets the names of **own** properties, not inherited ones. If the implementation of `ProgressError` on your browser's JavaScript engine implements those other propertise as accessors on a prototype (or even data properties on a prototype, though that seems unlikely), they're inherited. You can access inherited properties, but they won't be included in `getOwnPropertyNames`'s array.

If you modify your code a bit, you can see that `bubbles` (for instance) is on `err`'s prototype's prototype (at least in Chrome), and is indeed an accessor property:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  //console.log(this);
};
xhttp.onerror = function(err) {
  console.log("Error: ");
  let a;
  let level = 0;
  while (err) {
    a = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err);
      console.log("Error:", err);
      console.log("Props:", a.join(", "));
    if (a.includes("bubbles")) {
        console.log(`Found bubbles at ${level}:`, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(err, "bubbles"));
      break;
    }
    ++level;
    err = Object.getPrototypeOf(err);
  }
}
xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.google.com/", true); // CORS-blocking page to trigger the error
xhttp.send();
```

[image]

Simpler example:

```js
// Create an object with an `answer` property
const p = {
  answer: 42
};
// Create an object using that object as its prototype
const o = Object.create(p);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)); // []
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(o))); // ["answer]
```